# TortoiseSVN: Error message when committing a file

Tags: svn, svn-hooks

I am using TortoiseSVN to commit a file, but I am getting the following error message:

> Error   post-commit hook failed (exit code 25) with output:
>   Error   An unexpected error has occurred. The process at spawn ID exp5 has produced the following output:
>   Error   yes
>   Error
>   Error   Failed to add the host to the list of known hosts (/var/www/.ssh/known_hosts).
>       Error   Password:

What does this mean, how do I fix it?

Comment: You have a post-commit script that asks for a password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means (as written)

> post-commit hook failed

and it is not related to TortoiseSVN, but to the Subversion configuration on the **server side**. Some ugly not-tested-carefully script, added as a post-commit hook to the repository, returned a non-zero value (25). A non-zero exit code for a hook means "NOT OK here", and the output of running the failed post-commit hook is shown to you.

Locally, you *don't need to change anything*. You don't need to worry about it, because your changes were already committed. You *should* ask your repository-admin, "WTF, dude?!"